# Minecraft 1.8 Sign Command Help

Tags: minecraft-java-edition, minecraft-commands

Can anyone tell me what I'm doing wrong here? Command block said:

> Data tag parsing failed: Unbalanced Quotation:

I am creating a sign in Minecraft with multiple colors on a single line. The only thing I need is to execute a command upon right-click of the sign. I got the colors and everything working fine. I'm pretty new to this though, so sorry if I'm just missing a quote or something. ;)

This one works, I just need to add a click event:

```
/give @p sign 1 0 {BlockEntityTag:{Text2:"[\"\",{\"text\":\"[\",\"color\":\"gold\"},{\"text\":\"Assault\",\"color\":\"gray\"},{\"text\":\"]\",\"color\":\"gold\"},{\"text\":\"\",\"color\":\"dark_aqua\"}]",Text3:"[\"\",{\"text\":\"(Right-Click)\",\"color\":\"dark_gray\"}]",Text4:"[\"\",{\"text\":\"\",\"color\":\"\"}]",id:"Sign"}}
```

Like so:

```
clickEvent:{action:run_command, value:\"/tp @p 1027 62 1000 \"}
```

Here is the command that gave me the error:

```
/give @p sign 1 0 {BlockEntityTag:{Text2:"[\"\",{\"text\":\"[\",\"color\":\"gold\"},{\"text\":\"Assault\",\"color\":\"gray\"},{\"text\":\"]\",\"color\":\"gold\"},{\"text\":\"\",\"color\":\"dark_aqua\"}]",Text3:"[\"\",{\"text\":\"(Right-Click)\",\"color\":\"dark_gray\"}]",Text4:"[\"\",{\"text\":\"\",color\":\"blue\"}],id:"Sign",clickEvent:{action:run_command, value:\"/tp @p 1027 62 1000 \"}}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You did not close the `Text4` string tag with a quotation mark, and are missing a final closing curly bracket for the NBT data.

The click event is part of the JSON text component, so it must belong with one of them and not outside one of the strings as NBT. As well, click events only work on signs if they are a part of the parent object. Since you instantiate the components as an array, the very first record will be considered the parent.

You can also remove `id:"Sign"`, as it is redundant. Fixed command, modifying `Text4` to include a click event as the first record:

```
/give @p sign 1 0 {BlockEntityTag:{Text2:"[\"\",{\"text\":\"[\",\"color\":\"gold\"},{\"text\":\"Assault\",\"color\":\"gray\"},{\"text\":\"]\",\"color\":\"gold\"},{\"text\":\"\",\"color\":\"dark_aqua\"}]",Text3:"[\"\",{\"text\":\"(Right-Click)\",\"color\":\"dark_gray\"}]",Text4:"[{\"text\":\"\",\"color\":\"blue\",\"clickEvent\":{\"action\":\"run_command\",\"value\":\"/tp @p 1027 62 1000\"}}]"}}
```

Comment: Thank you so much for replying so soon! I'm sorry I haven't been able to get back to you recently because band has been taking up a lot of my time. Thanks again though, the command works and the syntax makes perfect sense!